# Is there any chance of resize UISearchBar texfield height?

Tags: ios, ios5, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I am googling and googling and I can't find anywhere how can I have a UISearchBar with more than 44px of height.

Is this possible in any way? I've seen many others SO posts, but no one worked.

I am using iOS 5.